# How to get tax rate in checkout SDK in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I tried searching but I can't seem to find a way to get the tax rate in Bigcommerce checkout page. I'm using the Bigcommerce checkout sdk but I can't find a way or a method to use to get the tax rate. All the taxes I find are total amount only and label. Is there a way to get the tax rate using an API call?